# CME Thrown for new ArrayList Initialization

Tags: java, android, exception, android-asynctask, concurrentmodificationexception

I am encountering a `ConcurrentModificationException` for the following:

```
  @MainThread
  private void notifyAdditionalItemsLoaded(
      final @Nullable List<RandomItem> newAdditionalItems) {
    if (newAdditionalItems != null) {
      eventListener.onAdditionalItemsLoaded(
          new ArrayList<>(newAdditionalItems));
    }
  }
```

The stack trace for the exception is:

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList$SubList.size(ArrayList.java:1057)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.toArray(AbstractCollection.java:139)
    at java.util.ArrayList.<init>(ArrayList.java:191)
    at com.dash.module.component.model.datasource.notifyAdditionalItemsLoaded(datasource.java:434)
    at com.dash.module.component.model.datasource.access$2300(datasource.java:42)
    at com.dash.module.component.model.datasource$LoadAdditionalRecordsTask.onPostExecute(datasource.java:599)
    at com.dash.module.component.model.datasource$LoadAdditionalRecordsTask.onPostExecute(datasource.java:540)
    at com.dash.util.BreadcrumbTask.onPostExecute(BreadcrumbTask.java:43)
    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:771)
    at android.os.AsyncTask.-$$Nest$mfinish(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:788)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8757)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1067)
```

As seen with the stack trace, `notifyAdditionalItemsLoaded()` is called from an async task's `onPostExecute()` method which simply sets the processing task to `null` and calls the `notify..` method:

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(@Nullable List<RandomItem> items) {
      loadAdditionalItemsTask = null; // reset
      notifyAdditionalItemsLoaded(items);
    }
```

And the `items` list is initialized within task, where new `RandomItem` objects are initialized and added to the list.

But, I am not sure why the CME is being thrown for shallow copying of objects to the list. And, this is not consistently reproducing.

Any help here would be very much appreciated. TYIA!

Comment: My first guess is that `newAdditionalItems` is being modified while the new `ArrayList` is being initialized. See if you can create a [mre] that exhibits the problem, pleas?